# Update related entity in a single sql round-trip

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

```
class Parent { Id, Name }
class Child { Id, Name, ParentId (notnull), Parent }
```

Given Id of Child object, and we have to update Name of its Parent. All should be done in a single sql round-trip. Something like:

```
UPDATE Parent SET
  Name = 'New name'
WHERE Id = (SELECT ParentId FROM Child WHERE Id = @id)
```

Comment: you can not use directly with EF, But you can use some Extension in ef like EntityFramework Extension to batch updaye. try Google Batch Update

Answer (score 0):

Normally, *if you have proper relations between entities*, you get Parent from Child entity, change it name and save changes:

```
Parent parent = context.Childs
    .Where(m => m.Id == id)
    .Select(m => m.Parent)
    .First();

parent.Name = "New name";
context.SaveChanges();
```

But as you see, there is two round-trips:

```
First: Select
Second: Update.
```

This is only way you can do this, at least as far as I know. But if you really need to query the database one time, you can give a try to [Raw Sql Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx). You can add method to your *repository* if you use repository pattern, or add extension methods for context, or how you like and update data. For example:

```
public static void UpdateParentName(this DbContext context, 
    int childId, 
    string parentName)
{
    // validate inputs
    // ..........

    string sqlCommand = 
        "UPDATE Parent SET Name = {1} WHERE Id = (SELECT ParentId FROM Child WHERE Id = {0})";
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlCommand, id, parentName);
}
```

Then call this method:

```
context.UpdateParentName(childId, "new name");
```